# How to add constraints to linear programming on variables not from objective function in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I am trying to solve a problem using linear optimization on matlab

```
 sum=zeros(5,1);
 for i=1:5
    min 2x1+3x2-5x3
    s.t.
      x1 <= 4;
      x2+3x3 <= 2;
      sum(1:i) >= 3

    sol=linprog(fill them)
    sum(i) = sum(i)+sol(2)-sol(3)
 end
```

How can I represent sum(i) in the matrices we use in linprog function?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `x4` and `x5` do not appear explicitly in the objective function does not necessarily mean they do not exist.
Think about this objective function

```
min 2*x1 + 3*x2 - 5*x3 + 0*x4 + 0*x5
```

Now you have a linear program with 5 variables.

Bottom line: just add two zeros to your objective function and you are done.